# Arduino API Authentication

Tags: api, basic-authentication, esp32

I'm working on a project and I have a problem since three days.
I'm doing this project with an ESP32 and want to connect it automatically to WIFI and get the API information.
The first part is okay, I did it without any problem. But it does not get the API Information.
My API-Link is something like this:

```
http://test.de/milad/api/Tv
```

And it needs a User and Password:

```
User: Demo
Pass: OIMLyyIR03QZTqN2KFZkDKneuuk5ixMgeGOHS7r3
```

I tried to read all the BASIC-Auth examples in internet. But I couldn't find the solution... I get this error:

```
[HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection refused
```

For example I used this code:

```
// wait for WiFi connection
if((wifiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    HTTPClient http;

    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    // configure traged server and url

    http.begin("http://test.de/milad/api/Tv");
    http.setAuthorization("demo", "OIMLyyIR03QZTqN2KFZkDKneuuk5ixMgeGOHS7r3");

    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
    // start connection and send HTTP header
    int httpCode = http.GET();

    // httpCode will be negative on error
    if(httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
        }
    } else {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }

    http.end();
```

Comment: Have you tested the API before?
`curl -u demo:OIMLyyIR03QZTqN2KFZkDKneuuk5ixMgeGOHS7r3 http://test.de/milad/api/Tv`
Can you tell us more about the server?

Comment: I see lots of logging here. Could you access and post these logs?
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L820

Comment: Thanks alot Androbin, the problem was the server.

Answer (score 0):

The server uses Digest Authentication while HTTPClient library on ESP32 currently only supports Basic Authentication.